# Laplace-Beltrami operator on sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose that we have solution of

$$\delta d f = g$$

on sphere. Where $\delta d$ is Laplace-de Rham operator for functions, $f,g$ are scalar functions and $g$ has support on north hemisphere and it is non-negative there.

Than by Stokes theorem we have(I think that I have signs wrong but that does not solve the problem)

$$
\int_{\text{equator}}*df = \int_{\text{north hemisphere}} d*df = - \int_{\text{south hemisphere}} d*df$$

But 
$$
\int_{\text{north hemisphere}} d*df = \int_{\text{north hemisphere}} *g \neq 0 $$
$$
\int_{\text{south hemisphere}} d*df = \int_{\text{south hemisphere}} *g = 0$$

What have I done wrong?? I can't really see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution. By Stokes's Theorem, since the sphere $S$ is compact,
$$\pm\int_S \star g = \int_S  d{\star}df = \int_{\partial S} \star df = 0\,,$$
since $\partial S = \emptyset$.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I expected that the solution will exist so I thought I have made a mistake.

Comment: So you are telling me that we cannot live on compact manifold? Since we would not have a nontrivial electromagnetic filed, [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) can be written as $d\star d A = J$

Comment: I'll have to ask my physicist friends what happens to Maxwell's equations on a compact manifold, but I'm pretty sure the classical equations you're thinking of work only in flat space, for starters.

Comment: Plus I would like to know if there is a way to define a winding number of closed manifold which lives on compact manifold. Normally I would do $w(x)=\int_S n_y \cdot \nabla G_x(y) d\sigma$ where $G_x(y)$ is fundamental solution of laplace-de rahm operator. Since the fundamental solution does not exist what can we do?